# Chinese characters not rendering php WordPress woo commerce

Tags: php, wordpress, character-encoding, woocommerce

I'm editing woocommerce order detail page. 
it has product variations which has in Chinese characters,

but those are  rendering like below. rest others are rendering Chinese characters correctly.

```
<dl class="variation">                      
    <dt class="variation-%e6%97%a5%e6%95%b8">%e6%97%a5%e6%95%b8:</dt>
    <dd class="variation-%e6%97%a5%e6%95%b8"><p>5日</p></dd>
</dl>
```

but this need to be like this

```
 <dl class="variation">                     
        <dt class="variation-日數">日數:</dt>
        <dd class="variation-日數"><p>5日</p></dd>
    </dl
```

i tried using this php code to render those special char to Chinese but no luck,

```
ob_start();
//this function directly display oputput, so i assign that to variable using ob
$item_meta->display();
$obf= ob_get_contents ();
ob_end_clean();
echo html_entity_decode($obf);
```

can anyone know how to do that, those variation correctly display on cart and product detail pages. the template file is woocommerce/order/order-details.php

you can see above output on http://sim.today/checkout/order-received/1400/?key=wc_order_53423853a6a8f

thanks

Answer (score 0):

i used `urldecode()` function and it works perfectly, but i'm not sure why it should use here :)